# How can I change the order of elements in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="right col-md-4">this should be on the right side and on the top (in small screen size)</div>
  <div class="left col-md-8">this should be on the left side and on the bottom (in small screen size)</div>
</div>

<style>
.container{
  border: 1px solid;
}

.right{
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.left{
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
</style>
```

**DEMO**

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid;
}

.right{
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.left{
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="right col-md-4">this should be on the right side and on the top (in small screen size)</div>
  <div class="left col-md-8">this should be on the left side and on the bottom (in small screen size)</div>
</div>
```

As you see in the demo, the red bordered box should be one the right side *(which is currently on the left side)* and should be on the top in small screen size *(which is in the top and correct position right now)*.

Anyway, how can I pull it on the right side? Noted that I don't want to use `pull-right` for it. because I need to make it center in small screen size.

Comment: Numerous ways to do this...all outlined in bootstrap docs

Comment: ever heard of !important, if not than you need better CSS classes

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right col-md-4 col-md-push-8">this should be on the right side and on the top (in small screen size)</div>
    <div class="left col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">this should be on the left side and on the bottom (in small screen size)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using PULL, I know you do not want to use it, but you can try it in the following way by combining it with PUSH

https://jsfiddle.net/m7vxm9cr/

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid;
}

.right{
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.left{
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="right col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-push-6 col-md-6">this should be on the right side and on the top (in small screen size)</div>
  <div class="left col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-pull-6 col-md-6">this should be on the left side and on the bottom (in small screen size)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `col-sm-6` and `col-xs-6` to handle small screen in [**bootstrap** then 
grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) then overwrite the `float:left` of `col-md-*` that is in bootsrap class using `.container .right{float:right}`

See code snippet

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container .right{
  border: 1px dashed red;
  float:right ;
}

.left{
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="right col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">this should be on the right side and on the top (in small screen size)</div>
  <div class="left col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">this should be on the left side and on the bottom (in small screen size)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.parent{display:flex;}.child1{order:1;}.child2{order:2;}`change the order of the child elements in media query.